# Resizing an open model view in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have a UIViewController displayed as a form sheet, and when a user selects a particular setting, the modal expands to show more data (similarly, it will also contract if they select something else).

In iOS 7 and below, it was possible to resize a modal view using

`[self.view.superview setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];`

In iOS 8, I am aware that you can use `setPreferredContentSize` to set the initial size of a popup, but this does not work to resize a currently displayed popup.

So my question is, how do you resize a displayed popover in iOS 8?

Comment: You should open modal with transparent background and have contentView inside it which you can resize easy

Comment: I didn't even think of that.  Using that method, though, the popup shadow is larger than the content when it's resized - any way to make it go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With b3ginneriOS's tip I was able to resolve the issue.

First I moved everything in the modal view controller into a subview, and applied all resize transitions to that instead (leaving the main view at the maximum size).

For iOS 8 only, use Presentation over current context.
In `prepareForSegue`

```
if(IS_IOS8) {
    [[segue destinationViewController] setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
}
```

And adding a semi-transparent background:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.45]];
```

With a few adjustments to correctly centre the view properly (depending on iOS7's superview resize and iOS8's subview), everything works nicely.